# how to create Entitlements.plist for push notification in XCODE 4.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, code-signing-entitlements

How to create Entitlements.plist for push notification in XCODE 4.2?

Can any one define for the path New File/Code Signing/Entitlements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible solution, have you imported the appropriate provisioning profile?

Go to Window->Organizer.

From the left side of the window choose LIBRARY -> Provisioning Profiles.

Choose Import (at the bottom) and import the APNs Provisioning Profile that you created for your app.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 4.2 there is no need to create entitlements.plist file. It is automatically generated in xcode 4 of upgraded versions.

Comment: As, if i am not creating entitlements file i am getting this error.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x15b200 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}" error.

Comment: just add "get-task-allow" and set as type "string" value is "BOOL" in Entitltements.plist file

Comment: Thanks for your response... but it is resolved without creating entitlements.plist file ?